# How to parse text file with multiple sections of headers in R?

Tags: r

I need to parse ascii file that has multiple sections of headers. The model snippet is below

```
Name1  | header1 | header2 | header3
header1|   11    |   x1
Name2  | header1 | header2 | header3
header1|   2.5   |   x2
header1|   3.7   |   x3
header1|   4.2   |   x4
Name3  | header1 | header2 | header3
header1|   34    |   x5
header1|   37    |   x6
etc.
```

My task is to compute variance for data from header1:

```
Names | Variances
-------------------------
Name1 | var(11)   # =NA
Name2 | var(c(2.5,3.7,4.2))
Name3 | var(c(34,37))
etc.
```

How to deal with such kind of files in R?

My real file is more complicated:

```
HD 4478 | velocities  |typ|    Value    R   m.e.  |A (Nmes)|na,Q,dom , res D| Obs.date | Rem.  |Or|     Reference     |
velocities  |V  |  -23.00        5.20   |D (    )|s , ,O   ,      |          |       |  |1992A&AS...95..541F|
BD +41 43| velocities  |typ|    Value    R   m.e.  |A (Nmes)|na,Q,dom , res D| Obs.date | Rem.  |Or|     Reference     |
velocities  |V  |   18.40        7.40   |D (    )|s , ,O   ,      |          |       |  |2007AN....328..889K|
velocities  |v  |   18.4                |D (   3)|  , ,    ,      |          |NN     |  |1979IAUS...30...57E|
velocities  |v  |   15.2                |  (   4)|  , ,    ,      |          |       |  |1970MmRAS..72..233H|
HIP 8855 | velocities  |typ|    Value    R   m.e.  |A (Nmes)|na,Q,dom , res D| Obs.date | Rem.  |Or|     Reference     |
velocities  |V  |  -10.00        7.40   |D (    )|s , ,O   ,      |          |       |  |1999A&AS..137..451G|
HD 215441 | velocities  |typ|    Value    R   m.e.  |A (Nmes)|na,Q,dom , res D| Obs.date | Rem.  |Or|     Reference     |
velocities  |v  |   -5.5                |  (  11)|  , ,    ,      |          |       |  |1969ApJ...156..967P|
velocities  |v  |                       |  (  18)|  , ,    ,      |          |V      |  |1960ApJ...132..521B|
HD 147010 | velocities  |typ|    Value    R   m.e.  |A (Nmes)|na,Q,dom , res D| Obs.date | Rem.  |Or|     Reference     |
velocities  |V  |   -3.96        1.41   |B (    )|s , ,O   ,      |          |       |  |2012ApJ...745...56D|
velocities  |V  |   -8.20        3.10   |C (    )|s , ,O   ,      |          |       |  |2006AstL...32..759G|
velocities  |v  |   -9                  |C (   3)|  , ,    ,      |          |NN     |  |1953GCRV..C......0W|
velocities  |v  |   -8.8                |  (   3)|  , ,    ,      |          |       |  |1950ApJ...111..221W|
```

The desired result is:

```
Names    | Variances
-------------------------
HD 4478  | var(-23.00)    # =NA
BD +41 43| var(c(18.40,18.4,15.2))
HIP 8855 | var(-10.00) # =NA
HD 215441| var(-5.5) # =NA
HD 147010| var(c(-3.96,-8.20,-9,-8.8))
```

Comment: `readLines` is always an option.

Comment: Do you want to do this at the command line or in R?

Comment: I want to do this in R script.

Comment: What kind of data is this?  There's probably a package for it if it's a common field of study

Comment: This is ascii output of astronomical database http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is to read your data properly. Maybe this format is specified somewhere? However, reading you sample data is possible within a few lines:

```
# read your ascii-file
asciitxt = readClipboard()
# find the headers (starting with "Name")
headers = which(grepl("^Name", asciitxt))
# split asciitext in groups
asciitxt = split(asciitxt, cumsum(seq_along(asciitxt) %in% headers))
# read asciitext as dataframe
l.in = lapply(asciitxt, function(x) read.table(text=x, header=T, sep="|", fill=T, stringsAsFactors=F))
# name the elements of your list
names(l.in) = sapply(l.in, function(x) names(x)[1])
# do your calculations
sapply(l.in, function(x) var(x$header1))
```

The problem with your real data is, the values you need for calculations aren't separated in one variable. for example in row 2, variable "typ" contains not only the value "23.00", but the string "   23.00    5.20    ". After read.table you have to dived somehow your variable "typ". Have a look at package tidyr::extract.

Comment: asciitxt = split(asciitxt, cumsum(grepl("^Name", asciitxt))) also works to split asciitext in groups. Thank you @MarkusN